# Web Push Notification library recommendation required

Tags: push-notifications

I am looking for a recommendation for a push notification library, which can send notifications easily to various clients on desktop chrome, firefox, IE and IPhone and Android browser users simultaneously.

I am using Java Jsp, Spring, and Javascript as technology stack. Kindly do not recommend frameworks based on Angular or similar technologies.